# Is there any API for automatic video treatment ? (auto-enhancing contrast, brightness...)

Tags: video, video-editing, api

I'm looking for a SDK / API that could help me perform automatic improvement of videos.

Something that would look like the Image editors "Auto-Enhance feature", that could improve brightness, contrast, colors etc... automatically.

I've seen manual post-treatments options (using FFMPEG filters for instance), but nothing that would make it automatic based on optimal output rendering.

I've also noticed "Smart filters" on softwares, but nothing I could install on the server or online service.

Is there any available tools on the market (SDK / APIs) that could help me in this task? Something like Adobe Premiere Auto Smart Tone, but for server?

Thanks

Criteria:

- Ideally would be Node.JS SDK, but can handle other languages.
- Pricing should be usage based ideally
- Commercial license

Comment: An online REST service? So you'll upload your 12 GB video, and get the 12 GB brightness enhanced video back? Then upload 12 GB again for contrast, get 12 GB back, upload 12 GB for colors, ... Sounds like crazy stuff that someone will eventually develop and become the richest man on earth

Comment: You're right, that's why I mainly said SDK. The videos I need them for are between 10 and 50MB. And the treatment could be done in one pass if applicable. But I get your point, I'm sure it won't exist as a REST service anytime soon. What I'm looking for is an equivalent of Photoshop Auto Smart Tone for a server.

Comment: Would a command-line tool installed on your server be OK if it fits your other criteria?

Comment: That would be great !